# How Select All Record From DataTable Distinct By Only One Column

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a datatable like this

```
invoice_number  invoice_date    customer_name   item_name
    1           14/01/2019          Mr.A            Item1
    2           15/01/2019          Mr.B            Item1
    3           15/01/2019          Mr.C            Item2
    1           15/01/2019          Mr.A            Item2
    2           20/01/2019          Mr.B            Item5
```

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6aax.png)

***What I Want***

I want to insert all the column **except 'item_name'** to a ListView. **My criteria is 'invoice_number' must be unique.** it doesn't matter what type of data is in other columns. it should look like this in ListView. Basically, grab the first occurrence and ignore the rest.

```
invoice_number  invoice_date    customer_name   
    1           14/01/2019          Mr.A            
    2           15/01/2019          Mr.B            
    3           15/01/2019          Mr.C
```

***What I have Tried So far***

```
Dim temp = (From p In Invoice_printing.Tables("inv_for_print").AsEnumerable()
                        Select New With {.inv_number = p.Field(Of String)("invoice_number"),
                                            .inv_date = p.Field(Of Date)("invoice_date"),
                                            .ol_name = p.Field(Of String)("ol_name")}).ToList()

            Dim inv_selected_date = temp.GroupBy(Function(x) New With {Key x.inv_number, Key x.inv_date, Key x.ol_name}).ToList()


            For Each inv In inv_selected_date
                Dim newItem As New ListViewItem(inv.Key.inv_number)
                newItem.SubItems.Add(inv.Key.ol_name)
                newItem.SubItems.Add(CType(inv.Key.inv_date, String))
                lv_inv_list.Items.Add(newItem)

            Next
```

Its worked but because of duplicated date, invoice number 1 and 2 appear twice in ListView. What should I do? My Linq knowledge is very limited. I can't think of anything other than putting the data into a multidimensional array, run a nested loop and remove the duplicated entry.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand...  Only the first instance of an `invoice_numer` will be allowed.  If there are any duplicates after the first instance, those rows will be ignored. Is that correct?

Comment: yes you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my comment under your question. If I understood you correctly, then I think this is what you want:

```
var inv_selected_date = temp.GroupBy(i => i.invoice_number).Select(iv => iv.First()).ToList();
```

Comment: isn't it only get the "invoice_number" column? As I stated, I want the all 3 columns.

Comment: I have converted it to VB and its giving me error at i.invoice_number   ----  Dim inv_selected_date = temp.GroupBy(Function(i) i.invoice_number).[Select](Function(iv) iv.First()).ToList()

Comment: I apologies about my earlier comment. its working perfectly. one small correction --- its not invoice_number its inv_number. Thank you for helping me out.